# Excel dashboard

Tags: excel, pivot-table, dashboard

I have created a dashboard on excel. Behind the dashboard there are raw data and pivot tables from which the dashboard is created. I want to copy all these sheets to another workbook and I am wondering if there is a quick and effective way to do this.

Comment: *I want to copy all these sheets* Copy the file and delete the worksheets with no use?

Comment: No , I want to keep both files

Comment: Duplicate the file then move the data from the other file.